# how to return a value from custom command in cypress

Tags: javascript, jquery, cypress, ui-automation, cypress-custom-commands

hi folks i am new in ui/cypress automation i am trying to create a custom command which read a data from ui and return it to calling command where i can compare it with test data and validate the result e.g.
[image]

for custom command in `support\commands.js`
below is my code
which take `companyname` as parameter and read the `contact info` from ui

```
Cypress.Commands.add('readContactInfo', (companyName) => {
cy.get('.simple-table__cell:nth-child(1)').contains(companyName).parent().within(function()
{
cy.get('div').eq(2).then(function(res)
{
cy.log(res.text())
})
})
})
```

and when i call the it from `test.spec.js` file like below

```
cy.readContactInfo('Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti')
```

the output is like

```
 log       Giovanni Rovelli
```

but i wanted that the `readContactInfo` will return the `text value` to the cypress command
like what normal function do..

what i tried

```
Cypress.Commands.add('readContactInfo', (companyName) => {
    cy.get('.simple-table__cell:nth-child(1)').contains(companyName).parent().within(function()
    {
    cy.get('div').eq(2).then(function(res)
    {
    return cy.wrap(res.text())
    })
    })
    })
```

and when i call the it from `test.spec.js` file like below

```
 cy.readContactInfo('Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti').then(text)=>{
cy.log(text);
}
```

the ouput is like

```
8  get        .simple-table__cell:nth-child(1)
9  -contain   Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti
10 -parent
11 -within
12 get        div
13 -eq        2
14 wrap       Giovanni Rovelli
l5 log        <li.simple-table__row>
```

Answer (score 3):

You are on the right track, but note you don't need to return anything, the `cy.wrap()` is enough (Cypress set's your `res.text()` as the current subject).

The problem is `.within()` always resets the subject, and since it wraps the subject you want it has the last word, so-to-speak.

Replace it with `.find()`

```js
Cypress.Commands.add("readContactInfo", (companyName) => {
  cy.get(".simple-table__cell:nth-child(1)")
    .contains(companyName)
    .parent()
    .find("div")
    .eq(2)
    .then(function (res) {
      return cy.wrap(res.text());
    });
});
```

You can also shorten the `res.text()`

```js
Cypress.Commands.add("readContactInfo", (companyName) => {
  cy.get(".simple-table__cell:nth-child(1)")
    .contains(companyName)
    .parent()
    .find("div")
    .eq(2)
    .invoke('text')
});
```

---

Ref [.within()](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/within#Yields)

> **Yields**
>
> .within() yields the same subject it was given from the previous command.

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to return the entire chain command of the subject you want to return.

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('readContactInfo', (companyName) => {
  return cy.get('.simple-table__cell:nth-child(1)')
    .contains(companyName)
    .parent()
    // find command limited to previous subject
    .find('div')
    .eq(2)
    // will invoke .text() and return it
    .invoke('text')
})
```

Now whenever you use the custom command, the text will be returned.

```js
cy.readContactInfo('Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti')
  .should('eq', 'text you want to verify here')
```

Comment: Right, I was thinking about a custom command for some reason. `.find()` is correct for this usage.